# minimum number of steps from 1 -> n with two operations

Tags: algorithm

Given a number *n*, find the minimum number of steps to get from 1 to *n* using only 2 operations:

1. Multiply by 2
2. Divide by 3

Is this possible to get to any *n* using only these two operations?

Comment: Assuming integer division (i.e. 16/3 = 5), then it's probably possible to generate any integer >= 1.

Comment: If you posted a question on math.stackexchange.com, you'd probably get a proof.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, then no.

If *n* equaled an integer that was not a power of 2, then you would not be able to reach that as you can't keep multiply 2's to 1 and get a non-power of 2. Dividing by 3 would just change the number to a fraction with a power of 3 in the denominator.

Comment: In computer programming, it maybe possible. As division operator return a integer. e.g. n = 5, 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16 and 16 / 3 = 5. But get "any" n requires some proof.